# Hautleook/AliceBundle fixture yml configuration with randomElement faker function

Tags: php, symfony, alice-fixtures

I am trying to configure the yml file for Hauleook/AliceBundle fixture.

```
Project\MainBundle\Entity\Manager:
   manager_{1..30}:
      name: '<firstName()> <lastName()>'
      profile_image: '9.jpg'
      profile_image_thumb: '<randomElement(['9.jpg','10.jpg'])'
```

And I am getting the following error message when i tried to run

bin/console   hautelook:fixtures:load

```
  [Nelmio\Alice\Exception\FixtureBuilder\ExpressionLanguage\LexException]  
  Could not lex the value "["10.jpg"".
```

Comment: **OPEN_APOSTROPHE** `<randomElement([` **CLOSE_APOSTROPHE** `9.jpg','10.jpg'])'`

Comment: @BrandonIbbotson is it supposed to be like

profile_image_thumb: OPEN_APOSTROPHE <randomElement([ CLOSE_APOSTROPHE 9.jpg','10.jpg'])'

Comment: You're terminating your string before the `9.jpg` part. You need to [escape](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php) the apostrophes so that they aren't regarded as string terminators.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you are using the 3.0.0.beta version can you downgrade to a stable version?

In 2.2.2 this syntax works for me:

```
'<randomElement( ["1", "2"] )>'
```

Comment: i tried profile_image_thumb: '<randomElement( ["1", "2"] )>'

and I am getting the following errors:

 [Nelmio\Alice\Exception\FixtureBuilder\ExpressionLanguage\LexException]  
  Could not lex the value "["1"".

Comment: @Ralph  I've edited my answer, it seems you are not using a stable version